# Cron Job - Read error (Connection timed out) in headers

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have recently taken over hosting a site that is run in EE (latest version). My EE knowledge is not amazing, however, this project my way to get into using it.

The site in question also uses SPEKTRIX to manage a whole bunch of things that go on at their venue. It also uses DataGrab to run some imports that automatically create instances with the EE site for the managers to then edit and open etc…

These DataGrab jobs are run as Cron jobs and they work fine. However, recently I have been getting these error through for one of the scripts.

```
--2014-05-27 07:05:01--  http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/auto-import
Resolving www.domain.co.uk... xxx.xx.xxx.x
Connecting to www.domain.co.uk|xxx.xx.xx.x|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/instances-import [following]

--2014-05-27 07:05:47--  http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/instances-import
Reusing existing connection to www.domain.co.uk:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

--2014-05-27 07:20:48-- (try: 2)  http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/instances-import
Connecting to www.domain.co.uk|xxx.xx.xxx.x|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.
```

I have no idea why this has suddenly started playing up when the same script gave the following response

```
--2014-05-24 09:05:01--  http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/auto-import
Resolving www.domain.co.uk... xxx.xx.xxx.x
Connecting to www.domain.co.uk|xxx.xx.xxx.x|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/instances-import [following]

--2014-05-24 09:05:19--  http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/instances-import
Reusing existing connection to www.domain.co.uk:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `auto-import.531'

0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  134M
50K .......... .                                           21387G=0s

2014-05-24 09:13:57 (165 MB/s) - `auto-import.531' saved [62682]
```

Any help would be appreciated in this guys

Thanks

/* UPDATE */

It is using wget via cpanel to run the scripts

5 0 * * * wget 'http://www.domain.co.uk/assets/auto/set-expiry-date.php'

5 * * * * wget 'http://www.domain.co.uk/spektrix/auto-import'

0 * * * * wget 'http://www.domain.co.uk/assets/auto/extend-expiry-date.php'

The auto-import is the only one that has the timeout issue.

It's also worth noting that when the timeout occurs causes the server to have a high CPU / memory load.

I have restarted cron and waited for the job to restart and ran the command 'top' while the cron was running

```
PID  USER    PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR  S %CPU   %MEM  TIME+     COMMAND           
1617 mysql   20  0 3 450m  244m 6008 S 234.1  1.2   17048:40  mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error, the request is timing out. Do you know what tool is used to grab this information ? The output looks like curl and curl has a ***--connect-timeout*** option which you can use to bump up the timeout value. The default is 5 minutes ; try bumping it up to 10 minutes to see if it takes care of the error.

Comment: The same option ( --connect-timeout=seconds )  would work for wget

Comment: It is in fact wget - i have the set up through cpanel

Comment: Did you add the option ( --connect-timeout=seconds ) and retry ?